# Global files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Where do I store a php file ( `functions.php`) in the laravel directory, so that I can call functions in it from any controller? I understand I am to `include` it in all the files where I have to use the functions, but I'm not very clear on where I need to put the file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put inside in your `App` directory.

After that add the following line to your `App\start\global.php` file

```
require app_path().'/functions.php';
```

That's it.

Comment: If I want to put it in `app/Functions`, is it `require app_path()./Functions/functions.php';` ?